# Select unique identifier of the last transaction within a group - Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the last transaction submitted by a specific user/account tuple (a user can have more than one account). This is my approach

```
SELECT last_tx.user_id, last_tx.account_id, last_tx.last_tx_date, tx_all.transaction_id
FROM   [info.all_transactions] AS tx_all 
       JOIN (SELECT user_id, 
                    account_id, 
                    Max(transaction_date) as last_tx_date 
             FROM   info.all_transactions 
             GROUP  BY user_id, 
                       account_id) AS last_tx 
         ON tx_all.user_id = last_tx.user_id 
            AND tx_all.account_id = last_tx.account_id 
            AND tx_all.transaction_date = last_tx.last_tx_date
```

but my result is empty. The primary key is transaction_id

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant You can upvote my question to help me increase my reputation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  user_id, 
  account_id, 
  transaction_date AS last_tx_date, 
  transaction_id
FROM(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, account_id ORDER BY transaction_date DESC) = 1 AS last_transaction
  FROM `info.all_transactions`
  )
WHERE last_transaction
```

You can test it with some dummy data, like below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `info.all_transactions` AS (
  SELECT '1' AS user_id, '1' AS account_id, '20170701' AS transaction_date, 1 AS transaction_id UNION ALL
  SELECT '1', '1', '20170702', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1', '2', '20170701', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2', '1', '20170701', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2', '1', '20170702', 5 
)
SELECT
  user_id, 
  account_id, 
  transaction_date AS last_tx_date, 
  transaction_id
FROM(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, account_id ORDER BY transaction_date DESC) = 1 AS last_transaction
  FROM `info.all_transactions`
  )
WHERE last_transaction
ORDER BY user_id, account_id
```

> Updated version to deal with Resource Exceeded Issue

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `info.all_transactions` AS (
  SELECT '1' AS user_id, '1' AS account_id, '20170701' AS transaction_date, 1 AS transaction_id UNION ALL
  SELECT '1', '1', '20170702', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1', '2', '20170701', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2', '1', '20170701', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2', '1', '20170702', 5 
)
SELECT row.* 
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(r ORDER BY transaction_date DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS row
  FROM `info.all_transactions` AS r
  GROUP BY user_id, account_id
)
ORDER BY user_id, account_id
```

Comment: I'm getting an 'Error: Resources exceeded during query execution.
' message.

Comment: @JuanDavid - got it. see updated version in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
#standardSQL
WITH data AS(
select '1' user_id, '1' account_id, '20170701' dt UNION ALL
select '1' user_id, '1' account_id, '20170702' dt UNION ALL
select '1' user_id, '2' account_id, '20170701' dt UNION ALL
select '2' user_id, '1' account_id, '20170701' dt UNION ALL
select '2' user_id, '1' account_id, '20170702' dt
)

SELECT
  *
FROM(
  SELECT
    user_id,
    account_id,
    FIRST_VALUE(dt) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, account_id ORDER BY dt DESC) max_dt
  FROM data
  )
GROUP BY
user_id, account_id, max_dt
```

Where `data` is a simulation of your `info.all_transactions`

Comment: I've tried to use a windows function (MAX instead FIRST_VALUE) and did not work. Nor with FIRST_VALUE as well (as you suggested in your answer). I'm getting the same row a lot of times. If I run your example in my shell, I receive this error: Error: Encountered " "WITH" "WITH "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting: <EOF> [Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]

Comment: You should enable standard sql (you do so by either unchecking "Use Legacy SQL" in the Options panel or by adding `#standardSQL` in your query). More info: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql

Comment: With #standardSQL I can run your example but the result is the same with a real query: https://ibb.co/hBuxEa

Comment: what you mean "result is the same with real query"? is it wrong?

Comment: That's right. With both approaches (mine and yours) I'm getting the same answer of the picture attached. The User Id and account Id are unique identifiers, but a user can have different accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (user_id, account_id ORDER BY transaction_date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM info.all_transactions t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This returns all the values on the row.  You can, of course, just select the columns that you need.